# How to await setting to state before mapping array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

'm trying to map some data that I have stored in an array (the screenshot below), but I can't seem to access it, because it is loaded asynchronously. How could I await the data? Is there a way to do it in the render function?

```
 render() {
         
        return (
          {this.state.serials.map((number) => {
    return number.s && number.s.length? 
    (
        <h2 > {number.s[0].a}</h2>
  ) : null
})}
        )
    }
```

This is componentDidMount() where I get my data:

```
componentDidMount() 
        const uid = this.state.user.uid;
        const gatewayRef = db.ref(uid + '/gateways');
        gatewayRef.on('value', (gateways_nums) => {
            const serialsArr = [];
          gateways_nums.forEach((gateway_num) => {
            const serialRef = db.ref('gateways/' + gateway_num.val()['gateway'])
            const last_temps =[];
            serialRef.on('value', (serials)=>{ 
                const ser = []
                serials.forEach((serial)=>{
                    ser.push(serial.val()['serial'])
                })
                last_temps.push({a: gateway_num.val()['gateway'], b: ser})
            })
            serialsArr.push({s:last_temps})
          });
          this.setState({serials:serialsArr})
        });
      }
```

I would really appreciate any help!

Comment: Initiate the serials state with empty array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working by changing the algorithm a bit. With this code there is no need for awating data:

```
    componentDidMount() {
    const uid = this.state.user.uid;
    const serialRef = db.ref(uid + '/gateways');

    serialRef.on('value', (serial_numbers) => {
      const serials = [];
      serial_numbers.forEach((serial_number) => {
        const za = serial_number.val()['gateway'];
        const last_temps = [];
        const tempRef = db.ref('gateways/' + za);
        tempRef.orderByChild("serial").on('value', (temps) => {
          const temparray = [];
          temps.forEach((temp) => {
            temparray.push(temp.val());
          })
          const last_temp = temparray;
          last_temps.push({ l: last_temp, za });
          this.setState({ last_temps: last_temps })
        })
        serials.push({ s: last_temps });
      });
      this.setState({ serials: serials });
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
render() {
  if(!this.state.serials) {
    // Ideally you should draw some loading spinner here
    // to indicate that data is not ready yet. But for a quick
    // solution you can just draw nothing
    return null
  }

  // Also "return ({ this.state.serials.map() })" is not valid syntax
  // you either need to return just an array without using braces, or
  // use some JSX tag and put braces inside of it
  return (
    <div>
        {this.state.serials.map(serial => ...)}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Speaking of invalid syntax with braces, you could also do

```
return this.state.serials.map(serial => ...)
```

Or (better)

```
return (
  <>
    {this.state.serials.map(serial => ...)}
  </>
)
```

If you don't want an extra div around your data

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however, this still hasn't solved it, because this.state.serial seems to be loaded, but it is still not mapping anything. If I write JSON.stringify(this.state.serials) the array is empty.

Comment: This means there is a problem in the algorithm that fetches this `serials` array in `componentDidMount`, try debugging it. I probably see the issue: you create `serialsArr`, then for every `serialRef` you set an `onvalue` handler. Notice that these handlers will be called asynchronously some time later. But then right after setting these listeners you do `this.setState({serials})`. So the listeners haven't been called yet, the array hasn't been populated, but you already save it into state, that's why it is empty inside `render`

Comment: Although I see that you push `{s:last_temps}` syncronously, so it shouldn't really be empty. This means that probably `gateway_nums` is empty, so nothing is pushed into the array. I am not sure, what technologies you use to populate this array, but you will have to debug it yourself or provide more details on how this is supposed to work. Seems like you fetch it from some database, maybe database is empty. Or maybe `forEach` also calls the callback asynchronously, so the push happens after `setState`. The point is, the problem seems to be in this algorithm